# How do I use FreeRTOS in C on a Raspberry Pi PicoW using Visual Studio Code and PlatformIO?

Tags: pi-pico, freertos

I'm trying to run FreeRTOS on a Raspberry Pi PicoW. I'm using Visual Studio Code with PlatformIO to connect to the Pico. I have a folder for the project where I put the FreeRTOS include files and the .c files (these files were downloaded from freertos.org, they're the FreeRTOS source files).

When I try to upload the program I get the following errors, which don't make sense since I already included the FreeRTOS source files and headers and there is no compilation error, only linker error:

```
Executing task: C:\Users\my_name\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run 

Processing pico (platform: raspberrypi; board: pico)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/raspberrypi/pico.html
PLATFORM: Raspberry Pi RP2040 (1.7.0) > Raspberry Pi Pico
HARDWARE: RP2040 133MHz, 264KB RAM, 2MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, jlink, raspberrypi-swd)
PACKAGES:
 - tool-rp2040tools @ 1.0.2
 - toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi @ 1.90201.191206 (9.2.1)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> https://bit.ly/configure-pio-ldf     
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\pico\src\Overload_PICO.o
Linking .pio\build\pico\firmware.elf
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\pico\src\Overload_PICO.o: in function `task1':
Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task1+0x2): undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task1+0x14): undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task1+0x28): undefined reference to `xTaskDelayUntil'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\pico\src\Overload_PICO.o: in function `task2':
Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task2+0x2): undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task2+0x14): undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task2+0x2a): undefined reference to `xTaskDelayUntil'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\pico\src\Overload_PICO.o: in function `task3':
Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task3+0x2): undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task3+0x14): undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.task3+0x2a): undefined reference to `xTaskDelayUntil'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\pico\src\Overload_PICO.o: in function `main':
Overload_PICO.c:(.text.startup.main+0x12): undefined reference to `xTaskCreate'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.startup.main+0x24): undefined reference to `xTaskCreate'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.startup.main+0x36): undefined reference to `xTaskCreate'
c:/users/my_name/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Overload_PICO.c:(.text.startup.main+0x3a): undefined reference to `vTaskStartScheduler'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\pico\firmware.elf] Error 1
=============================================== [FAILED] Took 2.80 seconds ===============================================
```

---

---

**Files I think are useful to know to answer my question**

This is the FreeRTOSConfig.h I'm using:

```
#ifndef FREERTOS_CONFIG_H
#define FREERTOS_CONFIG_H

/* Use Pico SDK ISR handlers */
#define vPortSVCHandler         isr_svcall
#define xPortPendSVHandler      isr_pendsv
#define xPortSysTickHandler     isr_systick

#define configUSE_PREEMPTION                    1
#define configUSE_PORT_OPTIMISED_TASK_SELECTION 0
#define configUSE_TICKLESS_IDLE                 0
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ                      133000000
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ                      100
#define configMAX_PRIORITIES                    5
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE                128
#define configMAX_TASK_NAME_LEN                 16
#define configUSE_16_BIT_TICKS                  0
#define configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD                 1
#define configUSE_TASK_NOTIFICATIONS            1
#define configTASK_NOTIFICATION_ARRAY_ENTRIES   3
#define configUSE_MUTEXES                       0
#define configUSE_RECURSIVE_MUTEXES             0
#define configUSE_COUNTING_SEMAPHORES           0
#define configQUEUE_REGISTRY_SIZE               10
#define configUSE_QUEUE_SETS                    0
#define configUSE_TIME_SLICING                  0
#define configUSE_NEWLIB_REENTRANT              0
#define configENABLE_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY     0
#define configNUM_THREAD_LOCAL_STORAGE_POINTERS 5
#define configSTACK_DEPTH_TYPE                  uint16_t
#define configMESSAGE_BUFFER_LENGTH_TYPE        size_t

/* Memory allocation related definitions. */
#define configSUPPORT_STATIC_ALLOCATION         0
#define configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION        1
#define configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP        1

/* Hook function related definitions. */
#define configUSE_IDLE_HOOK                     0
#define configUSE_TICK_HOOK                     0
#define configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW          0
#define configUSE_MALLOC_FAILED_HOOK            0
#define configUSE_DAEMON_TASK_STARTUP_HOOK      0

/* Run time and task stats gathering related definitions. */
#define configGENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS           0
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY                0
#define configUSE_STATS_FORMATTING_FUNCTIONS    0

/* Co-routine related definitions. */
#define configUSE_CO_ROUTINES                   0
#define configMAX_CO_ROUTINE_PRIORITIES         1

/* Software timer related definitions. */
#define configUSE_TIMERS                        1
#define configTIMER_TASK_PRIORITY               3
#define configTIMER_QUEUE_LENGTH                10
#define configTIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH            configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE

/* Define to trap errors during development. */
#define configASSERT( x )

/* Optional functions - most linkers will remove unused functions anyway. */
#define INCLUDE_vTaskPrioritySet                1
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskPriorityGet               1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelete                     1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend                    1
#define INCLUDE_xResumeFromISR                  1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelayUntil                 1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelay                      1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetSchedulerState          1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle       1
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark     0
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetIdleTaskHandle          0
#define INCLUDE_eTaskGetState                   0
#define INCLUDE_xEventGroupSetBitFromISR        1
#define INCLUDE_xTimerPendFunctionCall          0
#define INCLUDE_xTaskAbortDelay                 0
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetHandle                  0
#define INCLUDE_xTaskResumeFromISR              1

/* A header file that defines trace macro can be included here. */

#endif /* FREERTOS_CONFIG_H */
```

This is the platformio.ini I'm using:

```
[env:pico]
platform = raspberrypi
board = pico
monitor_speed = 115200
```

This is the portmacro.h I'm using, I'm not sure if this one is correct for the PicoW, I searched the internet and found that the Pico uses an ARM-Cortex M0 processor so I assumed this is the correct portmacro:

```
/*
 * FreeRTOS Kernel V10.4.6
 * Copyright (C) 2021 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates.  All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
 * this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
 * the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
 * use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
 * the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
 * subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
 * IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * https://www.FreeRTOS.org
 * https://github.com/FreeRTOS
 *
 */


#ifndef PORTMACRO_H
    #define PORTMACRO_H

    #ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
    #endif

/*-----------------------------------------------------------
 * Port specific definitions.
 *
 * The settings in this file configure FreeRTOS correctly for the
 * given hardware and compiler.
 *
 * These settings should not be altered.
 *-----------------------------------------------------------
 */

/* Type definitions. */
    #define portCHAR          char
    #define portFLOAT         float
    #define portDOUBLE        double
    #define portLONG          long
    #define portSHORT         short
    #define portSTACK_TYPE    uint32_t
    #define portBASE_TYPE     long

    typedef portSTACK_TYPE   StackType_t;
    typedef long             BaseType_t;
    typedef unsigned long    UBaseType_t;

    #if ( configUSE_16_BIT_TICKS == 1 )
        typedef uint16_t     TickType_t;
        #define portMAX_DELAY              ( TickType_t ) 0xffff
    #else
        typedef uint32_t     TickType_t;
        #define portMAX_DELAY              ( TickType_t ) 0xffffffffUL

/* 32-bit tick type on a 32-bit architecture, so reads of the tick count do
 * not need to be guarded with a critical section. */
        #define portTICK_TYPE_IS_ATOMIC    1
    #endif
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Architecture specifics. */
    #define portSTACK_GROWTH      ( -1 )
    #define portTICK_PERIOD_MS    ( ( TickType_t ) 1000 / configTICK_RATE_HZ )
    #define portBYTE_ALIGNMENT    8
    #define portDONT_DISCARD      __attribute__( ( used ) )
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* Scheduler utilities. */
    extern void vPortYield( void );
    #define portNVIC_INT_CTRL_REG     ( *( ( volatile uint32_t * ) 0xe000ed04 ) )
    #define portNVIC_PENDSVSET_BIT    ( 1UL << 28UL )
    #define portYIELD()                                 vPortYield()
    #define portEND_SWITCHING_ISR( xSwitchRequired )    do { if( xSwitchRequired ) portNVIC_INT_CTRL_REG = portNVIC_PENDSVSET_BIT; } while( 0 )
    #define portYIELD_FROM_ISR( x )                     portEND_SWITCHING_ISR( x )
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* Critical section management. */
    extern void vPortEnterCritical( void );
    extern void vPortExitCritical( void );
    extern uint32_t ulSetInterruptMaskFromISR( void ) __attribute__( ( naked ) );
    extern void vClearInterruptMaskFromISR( uint32_t ulMask )  __attribute__( ( naked ) );

    #define portSET_INTERRUPT_MASK_FROM_ISR()         ulSetInterruptMaskFromISR()
    #define portCLEAR_INTERRUPT_MASK_FROM_ISR( x )    vClearInterruptMaskFromISR( x )
    #define portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()                  __asm volatile ( " cpsid i " ::: "memory" )
    #define portENABLE_INTERRUPTS()                   __asm volatile ( " cpsie i " ::: "memory" )
    #define portENTER_CRITICAL()                      vPortEnterCritical()
    #define portEXIT_CRITICAL()                       vPortExitCritical()

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Tickless idle/low power functionality. */
    #ifndef portSUPPRESS_TICKS_AND_SLEEP
        extern void vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep( TickType_t xExpectedIdleTime );
        #define portSUPPRESS_TICKS_AND_SLEEP( xExpectedIdleTime )    vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep( xExpectedIdleTime )
    #endif
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Task function macros as described on the FreeRTOS.org WEB site. */
    #define portTASK_FUNCTION_PROTO( vFunction, pvParameters )    void vFunction( void * pvParameters )
    #define portTASK_FUNCTION( vFunction, pvParameters )          void vFunction( void * pvParameters )

    #define portNOP()

    #define portMEMORY_BARRIER()    __asm volatile ( "" ::: "memory" )

    #ifdef __cplusplus
        }
    #endif

#endif /* PORTMACRO_H */
```

Code I'm trying to upload:

```
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <task.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//Overload happens if xTaskGetTickCount – lastTickCount (the first parm to vTaskDelayUntil) is >= period in ticks

void delay(int number_of_seconds)
{
    // Converting time into milli_seconds
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;
 
    // Storing start time
    clock_t start_time = clock();
 
    // looping till required time is not achieved
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds)
        ;
}

void task1();
void task2();
void task3();

int main() {
  
  //Create tasks
//xTaskCreate(Task function, Task name, , Task parameter, Task priority, );    
  xTaskCreate(task1, "task1", 128, NULL, 1, NULL);
  xTaskCreate(task2, "task2", 128, NULL, 2, NULL);
  xTaskCreate(task3, "task3", 128, NULL, 3, NULL);
  vTaskStartScheduler();

}

void loop() {}

void task1() {

  TickType_t waketime, period = 10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

  waketime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  while(1) {

    printf("M"); //This happens almost immediately, so we need to add an artificial delay, a  to simulate a task running for a few ms, it only serves as a notification that the task started
    delay(100);
    if(xTaskGetTickCount() - waketime >= period) printf("Overload in task 1");
    vTaskDelayUntil(&waketime, period);
  
  }

}

void task2() {

  TickType_t waketime, period = 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

  waketime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  while(1) {

    printf("E"); //This happens almost immediately, so we need to add an artificial delay, a  to simulate a task running for a few ms, it only serves as a notification that the task started
    delay(10);
    if(xTaskGetTickCount() - waketime >= period) printf("Overload in task 2");
    vTaskDelayUntil(&waketime, period);
  
  }

}

void task3() {

  TickType_t waketime, period = 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

  waketime = xTaskGetTickCount();

  while(1) {

    printf("S"); //This happens almost immediately, so we need to add an artificial delay, a  to simulate a task running for a few ms, it only serves as a notification that the task started
    delay(10);
    if(xTaskGetTickCount() - waketime >= period) printf("Overload in task 3");
    vTaskDelayUntil(&waketime, period);
  
  }

}
```